# How to constrain edge slide to axis?

Tags: edit-mode, edges, axis

Trying to do a simple edge slide but it keeps twisting at angles when moved.  I am trying to just move them along its connected path whilst keeping the vertical alignment.

Because the top is curved, it is longer and twists? Any help appreciated, thanks.
no photo as file is deleted to start again. but answer still desired.

[image]

Comment: could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: I'm afraid it is still very vague   :/   a screenshot would really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the extra edge you have on the top surface.

You can enable *clamp* (hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> or press <kbd>C</kbd>) after sliding the edge far away from it, but it's not perfect. Removing the edge works best, if you don't need it:

[image]

---

To get an edge where you've indicated, you might find it easier to use the knife tool, at least in this case:

1. Line up the view with the orientation you want the edge to be in (and ensure you're in orthographic view, <kbd>numpad 5</kbd>)
2. Start the knife tool with <kbd>K</kbd>
3. Click the top vertex, enable angle constrain (<kbd>C</kbd>)
4. Click the bottom edge:

[image]

Note that there are many ways you can go about doing this, for example vertex snapping combined with axis constraints can solve this and many similar puzzles:

1. Set the snapping type to *Vertex*
2. Grab (<kbd>G</kbd>) the top vertex and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap it to other vertices.
3. Grab the bottom vertex, constrain to the the X Y plane (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>), and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while hovering over the top vertex.

[image]

Comment: Note: I am trying to snap to the vertice you have deleted :)

Comment: @dave44 I've updated my answer